# ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected while creating user

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

When I create a admin user with:

```
GRANT ALL ON * TO my_name@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'my_passwd' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I received the error message "`ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be saying it like below by qualifying it with database name. Check [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) for more information.

```
 GRANT ALL ON db_name.*
```

So for your case,

```
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO my_name@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'my_passwd' 
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: or for all databases use `GRANT ALL ON *.* ...`